# Bootstrap Responsive Nav Open by default

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm working on a website (http://www.nantwichfoodfestival.co.uk) where I have used Twitter Bootstrap's v 2.3.2. My issue is that the responsive nav won't close by default on a mobile device.

Can someone help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh man, because you are calling the collapse function, which you should not.

Your main.js file has

```
$(".collapse").collapse();
```

Remove this.

See demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/czaLX/